# Stairs - material being used

Tags: stairs, plywood, particle-board

We are having a 2 story house built. On the majority of our stairs, it is not possible to use real wood due to the size of the stairs being over 12 inches wide. The builders have used different materials on stairs (with no apparent reason - I asked).

On some of the stairs it is treated plywood. On others it is particle board that is also used for the floors upstairs.

Which is better? Does it matter that they are inconsistent?

Comment: Are these the final stair treads, or are these temporary treads for use during construction? Do your plans call for carpeting the stairs? Are you sure its [particle board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_board), not [OSB (Oriented Strand Board)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_strand_board)? I'd be concerned about particle board, but not OSB.

Comment: I would not want particle board or just any old scrap on my stair tred’s. What is the thickness of the material? Any pic’s.

Comment: Do you really mean 12" deep?

Comment: How thick is the 'particle board'? Can you post a pic?

Comment: Don't they grow tress larger than 12" over there?